# Simple Awk Bash Script with UDVs

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

Here is my code:

```
!/bin/bash

#Basic Syntax - pfc.sh [filename] [keyword] [delimiter]

cat $1 |awk -F $2 '{print $2}' |awk -F $3 '{print$1}'
```

This works as is, however the 2nd and 3rd variables need to be surrounded by single ticks to work and I would not like for this to be necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question? Is the piece of code an exact replica of what you have?

Comment: You mean the `'{print $2}'` part? That needs to be single quoted in order to avoid `$1` and `$2` being expanded to the corresponding positional parameters. Single quoted strings are treated literally, whereas double quoted ones can have variable and parameter expansions.

Comment: No the print parts are fine, my problem is that when you use awk -F you need single ticks surrounding your inputs which I don't want my users to have to enter.

Comment: My question is: How do I add single ticks to my variables so my team doesn't have to. 

Example of how it currently works:

`sh pfc.sh variable1 'variable2' 'variable3'`

Comment: Can variable2 and variable3 contain white space?

Comment: At times variable3 can be only a whitespace yes.

Comment: I would like to modify the script so it can be simpler to run 
`sh pfc.sh variable1 variable2 variable3`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add single ticks to my variables so my team doesn't have to.

Example of how it currently works:

```
 sh pfc.sh variable1 'variable2' 'variable3'
```

Sorry, there is no work around for that. Single quotes(*not ticks*) tells the shell to interpret the pattern literally. For example consider that you have `'my argument'`,with out enclosing the argument inside single quotes, the shell interprets it as two arguments - `my` and `argument`.

For the same reason, your script too is flawed. It should have been

```
cat "$1" |awk -F "$2" '{print $2}' |awk -F "$3" '{print $1}' 
# mind the double quotes which prevents word splitting
# And you can't replace double quotes with single quotes as 
# variable expansion will not happen inside single quotes.
```

Comment: and of course, "$1" can be an input to fhe first `awk`, i.e. `awk '{stuff}' "$1" | awk ..` rather than using `cat "$1" |`. Good luck to all.